# Git revert creates conflict "deleted by us" due to rename

Tags: git, merge-conflict-resolution, git-revert

I'm trying to revert a commit made that modified a file that has since been renamed.

The file modified used to be called `bin/internal/call_parser.rb`, and is currently called `lib/call_parser.rb`, and I'm getting in my status after trying to do a revert

```
$ git status
# On branch master
# Your branch is ahead of 'origin/master' by 16 commits.
#
# Changes to be committed:
#   (use "git reset HEAD <file>..." to unstage)
#
#   modified:   other/unrelated/file
#
# Unmerged paths:
#   (use "git reset HEAD <file>..." to unstage)
#   (use "git add/rm <file>..." as appropriate to mark resolution)
#
#   deleted by us:      bin/internal/call_parser.rb
#
```

As far as I can tell, the current version of lib/call_parser.rb and the then version of the file bin/internal/call_parser.br ought to be similar enough that git can detect the shared content (I've heard that git works on file content, not on file names). How can I tell git to work harder in order to detect the rename and therefore do the revert to content within lib/call_parser.rb ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
git mv lib/call_parser.rb bin/internal/call_parser.rb
# Do the revert
git mv bin/internal/call_parser.rb lib/call_parser.rb
```

Probably hacky, but Worked For Me (TM).